# Which elements are in $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\backslash \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have  $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\ = \{\emptyset\}$. And $x \in \mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\backslash \emptyset$ means that $x \in \{\emptyset\} $ and $x \notin \emptyset$. I think that $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$. Hence $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\backslash \emptyset = \{\emptyset \}$, but the solution for this task says that $|\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)\backslash \emptyset| = 0$.

Comment: The solution is wrong, you are right.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Could it be that the task asks for $\vert P(\emptyset) \setminus \{\emptyset\} \vert$?

Comment: And if the answer to G.Chiusole's question is no, then keep in mind that many people still confuse $A\setminus x$ and $A\setminus \{x\}$ : a lot of the time, you can quickly get what is meant from context (e.g. in a non set theory context, $\mathbb R\setminus 0$ is "clear"); but there are times where the context does not allow for the "simplification". Your exercise is one of those times and so tou are definitely correct

Comment: Note that if the task is from a TeXed task sheet, it might be that whoever wrote it forgot to write the curly braces as `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Also, in many contexts, notation is simplified so that $A\setminus x$ actually stands for $A\setminus\{x\}$..